# ERROR:permission_manager_qt.cpp(82) Unsupported permission type: 13

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I am working on python code (PyQt 5.13) with built-in browser functionality.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineProfile, QWebEnginePage


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.webview = QWebEngineView()
        webpage = QWebEnginePage(self.webview)

        self.useragent = QWebEngineProfile(self.webview)

        agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246"
        self.useragent.defaultProfile().setHttpUserAgent(agent)

        self.webview.setPage(webpage)
        self.webview.setUrl(QUrl("http://whoer.net/"))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.webview)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

All works fine but some content are not loading and on the same time, cmd gives error

```
[10900:16264:0831/013730.858:ERROR:permission_manager_qt.cpp(82)] NOT IMPLEMENTEDUnsupported permission type: 13
[10900:16264:0831/013730.859:ERROR:permission_manager_qt.cpp(82)] NOT IMPLEMENTEDUnsupported permission type: 13
[10900:16264:0831/013733.144:ERROR:permission_manager_qt.cpp(82)] NOT IMPLEMENTEDUnsupported permission type: 13
[10900:16264:0831/013733.144:ERROR:permission_manager_qt.cpp(82)] NOT IMPLEMENTEDUnsupported permission type: 13
[10900:16264:0831/013737.063:ERROR:permission_manager_qt.cpp(82)] NOT IMPLEMENTEDUnsupported permission type: 13
[10900:16264:0831/013737.064:ERROR:permission_manager_qt.cpp(82)] NOT IMPLEMENTEDUnsupported permission type: 13
[10900:16264:0831/013753.618:ERROR:permission_manager_qt.cpp(82)] NOT IMPLEMENTEDUnsupported permission type: 13
[10900:16264:0831/013951.389:ERROR:permission_manager_qt.cpp(82)] NOT IMPLEMENTEDUnsupported permission type: 13
```

What's the problem ? I try to run cmd as an administrator but the error remais same. How can i assign permission to the code or that file (permission_manager_qt.cpp) to work fine.

Comment: example is given now in edit ...

Answer (score 3):

**TL; DR;** There is no way to handle these permissions since QtWebEngine has disabled that possibility.

---

The problem has nothing to do with program execution permissions.

Qt WebEngine is written on the basis of chromium so the Qt developers do not currently implement all the functionalities but will add more functionalities little by little. In this case, the permissions available by [chromium](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/content/public/browser/permission_type.h#L20) are:

```cpp
enum class PermissionType {
  MIDI_SYSEX = 1,
  // PUSH_MESSAGING = 2,
  NOTIFICATIONS = 3,
  GEOLOCATION = 4,
  PROTECTED_MEDIA_IDENTIFIER = 5,
  MIDI = 6,
  DURABLE_STORAGE = 7,
  AUDIO_CAPTURE = 8,
  VIDEO_CAPTURE = 9,
  BACKGROUND_SYNC = 10,
  FLASH = 11,
  SENSORS = 12,
  ACCESSIBILITY_EVENTS = 13,
  CLIPBOARD_READ = 14,
  CLIPBOARD_WRITE = 15,
  PAYMENT_HANDLER = 16,
  BACKGROUND_FETCH = 17,
  IDLE_DETECTION = 18,
  PERIODIC_BACKGROUND_SYNC = 19,
  WAKE_LOCK_SCREEN = 20,
  WAKE_LOCK_SYSTEM = 21,

  // Always keep this at the end.
  NUM,
};
```

But in the case of [Qt WebEngine](https://github.com/qt/qtwebengine/blob/44303861fd116b3a279d26300147e89a0bf8121c/src/core/permission_manager_qt.cpp#L55) does not handle all cases:

```cpp
ProfileAdapter::PermissionType toQt(content::PermissionType type)
{
    switch (type) {
    case content::PermissionType::GEOLOCATION:
        return ProfileAdapter::GeolocationPermission;
    case content::PermissionType::AUDIO_CAPTURE:
        return ProfileAdapter::AudioCapturePermission;
    case content::PermissionType::VIDEO_CAPTURE:
        return ProfileAdapter::VideoCapturePermission;
    case content::PermissionType::FLASH:
    case content::PermissionType::NOTIFICATIONS:
    case content::PermissionType::MIDI_SYSEX:
    case content::PermissionType::PROTECTED_MEDIA_IDENTIFIER:
    case content::PermissionType::MIDI:
    case content::PermissionType::DURABLE_STORAGE:
    case content::PermissionType::BACKGROUND_SYNC:
    case content::PermissionType::SENSORS:
    case content::PermissionType::ACCESSIBILITY_EVENTS:
        break;
    case content::PermissionType::CLIPBOARD_READ:
        return ProfileAdapter::ClipboardRead;
    case content::PermissionType::CLIPBOARD_WRITE:
        return ProfileAdapter::ClipboardWrite;
    case content::PermissionType::PAYMENT_HANDLER:
    case content::PermissionType::NUM:
        break;
    }
    return ProfileAdapter::UnsupportedPermission;
}
```

For example in your case the warning message:

```
... NOT IMPLEMENTEDUnsupported permission type: 13
```

It follows that the `PermissionType::ACCESSIBILITY_EVENTS` permission is required, but according to the QtWebEngine logic return a `ProfileAdapter::UnsupportedPermission` which is what the warning message indicates.

**Conclusion:**

- There is no way to solve from your side since it is a Qt/chromium warning, besides it is not an error it is only indicating that you do not have that permission.

Comment: but due to that .. the browser doesn't perform complete functionality as desktop browser perform .... so how can we deal it ..

Comment: @AsadSeeker There is no way to handle it, unless you want to create your own of QtWebEngine: download the source code, implement your logic obviously respecting the rules of the Qt private API, compile it QtWebEngine, recompile PyQtWebEngine. So the short answer is: There is no way, we just have to wait for those permits to be enabled in the future + the logic that entails it.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the warning (other than your suggestion of editing source code)?

Comment: @MikeBourbeau try add `os.environ["QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS"] = "--disable-logging"` before `app = QApplication(sys.argv)`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you! That didn't work for me, but I googled your suggestion and found docs for QtWebEngine logging. This worked for me: os.environ["QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS"] = "--enable-logging --log-level=3"

Comment: Just correcting formatting of the last comment because it's the best soluting for this issue and works for me as well: 


`os.environ["QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS"] = "--enable-logging --log-level=3"`   

`app = QApplication(sys.argv)`