# Opening PDF files with PyQt5 QtWebEngineWidgets

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt5, qtwebengine, pdf-viewer

I am trying to view a pdf file with QtWebEngineWidgets but I get "your file was not found" in the window. First time trying QtWebEngineWidgets. Please see the result in pic below.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

PDFJS = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "pdfjs/web/viewer.html")).toString()

class PdfReport(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def load_pdf(self, filename):
        url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename).toString()
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput("%s?file=%s" % (PDFJS, url)))

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(640, 480)


class Foo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pdf = PdfReport()
        filename = "summary_equipment_evaluation.pdf"
        self.pdf.load_pdf(filename)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.pdf)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Foo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

UPDATE: After downloading pdfjs, I get this empty window:

[image]

Comment: I have tested these codes and they work, they allow to show a pdf in a Qt window, maybe you have had problems in the implementation so you should show in detail what you have tried. Please use  `@username`

Comment: I tried to run code in your reply here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866298/qwebengineview-update-with-pdf-path by changing pdf path but I get "Your file was not found" in window.

Comment: @eyllanesc added pic above

Comment: Show the code, an image does not help. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: @eyllanesc just updated the question with details. Thanks!

Comment: You have an error, you have to use the fullpath (the file name is not enough)

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried that as well but get the same error.

Comment: add `print(QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput("%s?file=%s" % (PDFJS, url)))` after `self.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput("%s?file=%s" % (PDFJS, url)))` and tell me what you get (obviously using the fullpath)

Comment: @eyllanesc PyQt5.QtCore.QUrl('file:///G:/QC Report Generation/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=file:///G:/QC Report Generation/PDFs/summary_equipment_evaluation.pdf')

Comment: Do you have the unzipped pdfjs folder next to your script?

Comment: @eyllanesc  No, do I need to download it from somewhere?

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry to bother too much but after downloading pdfjs I get the result shown above. It looks like I am close but can't still open the pdf.  PyQt5.QtCore.QUrl('file:///G:/QC_Report_Generation/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=file:///G:/QC_Report_Generation/PDFs/summary_equipment_evaluation.pdf')

Comment: Try the following example (which no longer needs jspdf): https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/7566bab2f8a91593c460015ee2151717

Comment: @eyllanesc I got empty window, the same even I select pdf manually.

Comment: In that code I have added some print, what version of Qt and PyQt are printed?

Comment: PyQt5 version: 5.9.2, Qt version: 5.9.6

Comment: There is the problem, you have a very old version. Use the latest versions: `python -m pip install pyqt5==5.15.4 pyqtwebengine==5.15.4`

Comment: I get this error but it works:  "[73952:43052:0830/170726.780:ERROR:extension_function_dispatcher.cc(487)] Permission denied for metricsPrivate.recordValue "   How can I suppress it?

Comment: See my comments on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733039/errorpermission-manager-qt-cpp82-unsupported-permission-type-13/57740149#57740149